# PDO Disabled in PHP... how to enable it?

Tags: mysql, php, pdo

Sorry I'm still a bit of a novice with dedicated hosting. Anyway, we have a dedicated server running cPanel and WHM. I have full terminal access and all that.

Basically I've tried to install [Chive](http://chive-project.com) to a user on my server's account. Unfortunately whenever I login with any details, I get the following error:

> ```
> Internal Server Error
>
> include(PDO.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]:
> ```
>
> failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory
>
> ```
> An internal error occurred while the Web server was processing your
> ```
>
> request. Please contact the webmaster
>   to report this problem.
>
> ```
> Thank you.
> ```

My research shows from  that `--disable-pdo` is in the Configure Command list. What I want to know is how can I change this and turn it off? I have these two lines at the end of my php.ini file:

`extension=pdo.so 
extension=pdo_mysql.so`

(There's a linebreak between them but SF isn't showing it...)

But still it's not working. I can't find anywhere in php.ini that defines --disable-pdo - so where do I change this?

Thanks!

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this : 
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=680039

Answer (score 0):

That statement isn't showing PDO is not compiled (though it looks like it isn't) it is stating that some PHP script is trying to include a file called PDO.php. What line or file is given? It looks like you edited the message.

Comment: No, I didn't edit the message. It came straight out of Chive (http://chive-project.com), an Ajax-based alternative to phpMyAdmin. It used PDO but I've got the problem sorted now, thank you.